# Derive density of $Z=XY$, $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function, change-of-variable

I have been stumped for a few days on this. I have two random variables $X\sim U(0,1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, which are independent. How can I get the density of $Z = XY$?

I put $Z = XY, W = Y$ i.e. $X=Z/W, Y=W$ and achieved the Jacobian as $J={1\over|W|}$,
but I've got
$f_{Z,W}(z,w)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}|w|}{\exp(-w^2/2)}$
and I don't know how to integrate this w.r.t $w$ and get the (marginal) density of $Z$.
Could you please help me with this problem? I tried partial integration too but it doesn't work.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's a good idea to at least spell check your work before posting.  Putting effort into your post will invoke a more positive response.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you for your advice. I am a new comer to this community and I'm not familar with English, actually. I'm sorry if my post bothered others and I'll put more effort on it.

Comment: @angryavian Yes, they are.

Comment: If $\Phi$ and $\phi$ denote the CDF and PDF of the standard normal distribution, then the CDF of $Z$ is
$P(Z \le z) = P(XY \le z) = \int_0^1 P(Y \le z/x) \, dx = \int_0^1 \Phi(z/x) \, dx$
so the PDF of $Z$ is
$f_Z(z) = \frac{d}{dz} P(Z \le z)
= \int_0^1 \frac{\phi(z/x)}{x} \, dx$. It looks like this could be written in terms of an incomplete gamma function, but I am not sure if there is a nice expression for this. [Also, there might be errors in my computation.]

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I just checked your correction. Thank you so much!

Comment: @angryvian Thank you for your answer! I'll try once more with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
{\cal P}\pars{z} & \equiv
\totald{}{z}\int_{-\infty}^{z}{\cal P}\pars{z'}\dd z'
\\[2mm] & =
\totald{}{z}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\Theta\pars{z - xy}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}\delta\pars{z - xy}
\dd x\,\dd y
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{1}{\delta\pars{x - z/y} \over \verts{y}}\dd x\,\dd y
\\[2mm] & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}
\bracks{0 < {z \over y} < 1}{\dd y \over \verts{y}}
\\[2mm] & =
\bracks{z < 0}\int_{-\infty}^{z}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}
{\dd y \over -y} +
\bracks{z > 0}\int_{z}^{\infty}
{\expo{-y^{^2}\,/2} \over \root{2\pi}}
{\dd y \over y}
\\ & = \bbx{\Gamma\pars{0,z^{2}/2} \over 2\root{2\pi}}.
\\ & \Gamma\pars{0,\cdots}\
\mbox{is the}\ Incomplete\ Gamma\ Function.
\end{align}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

angryavian's comment seems to be the way to get a close to numerical answer.

Incase you were interested visually in the density here is a plot with $10^7$ samples. It seems to be strangely convex, my guess is that it would have looked very normal.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer made me understand better.

Comment: @jjj glad to help! very nice problem

Answer (score 0):

> I put $Z = XY, W = Y$ i.e. $X=Z/W, Y=W$ and achieved the Jacobian as $J={1\over|W|}$, but I've got $f_{Z,W}(z,w)={1\over\sqrt{2\pi}|w|}{\exp(-w^2/2)}$
> and I don't know how to integrate this w.r.t $w$ and get the (marginal) density of $Z$.

That is okay, but you forgot the support.   Always note the support!    Doing so will give you the same result as @FelixMarin obtained.

$\qquad\begin{align}f_{Y,Z}(y,z)&=f_{Y,XY}(y,z) \\&= \begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\partial z/y}{\partial z}\end{vmatrix} f_{X,Y}(z/y,y)\\&=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{1}{y}\end{vmatrix}\dfrac{\exp(-y^2/2)}{\surd(2\pi)}\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq z/y\leq 1}\,\mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb R}\\&=\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{1}{y}\end{vmatrix}\dfrac{\exp(-y^2/2)}{\surd(2\pi)}\,(\mathbf 1_{0\leq z\leq y}+\mathbf 1_{y\leq z\leq 0})\\[3ex] f_Z(z) &= \mathbf 1_{0\leq z}\int_z^\infty \dfrac{\exp(-y^2/2)}{y\surd(2\pi)}\mathrm d y-\mathbf 1_{z<0}\int_{-\infty}^z\dfrac{\exp(-y^2/2)}{y\surd(2\pi)}\mathrm d y\\&=\mathbf 1_{z\in\Bbb R}\int_{\lvert z\rvert}^\infty\dfrac{\exp(-y^2/2)}{y\surd(2\pi)}\mathrm d y\\&~~\vdots\\&=\dfrac{\Gamma(0, z^2/2)}{2\surd(2\pi)}\,\mathbf 1_{z\in\Bbb R}\end{align}$

Where the incomplete gamma function is defined as $\Gamma(a,x):=\int_x^\infty t^{a-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm d t$ so

$$\Gamma(0, z^2/2) = \int_{z^2/2}^\infty t^{-1}\exp(-t)\,\mathrm d t$$